# CASE issue, or is it how I've joined my table

Tags: sql, case

In Yellowfin want to return one value, I have 3 tables called 
memberships,
membershipPlans,
membershipUDPs.

Member is the main one with outer joins to the other two (a link may or may not exist)

so if MemberPlans.PrevFundID has an entry I want that, 
else if they joined less than 3 month ago I want MembershipUDPs.Property 
otherwise I want a text phrase.

Currently I'm getting 2 rows per memberships.MemberNo, one showing the PRevFundID and another showing MembershipsUDPs, I just want one row:
The sql shown is generated via Yellowfin

```
    SELECT DISTINCT
      "Memberships"."MemberNo",
      CASE
        WHEN PrevFundID IS NOT NULL  THEN PrevFundID
     ELSE 
       CASE
          WHEN JOINDATE >= DATEADD(mm, -3, GETDATE()) THEN Property 
          ELSE 'New to PHI'
       END
     END,
     "MembershipPlans"."PrevFundID",
     "MembershipUDPs"."Property"
   FROM "dbo"."Memberships"
   LEFT OUTER JOIN "dbo"."MembershipPlans"
     ON ("Memberships"."MemberNo" = "MembershipPlans"."MemberNo")
   LEFT OUTER JOIN "dbo"."MembershipUDPs"
     ON ("Memberships"."MemberNo" = "MembershipUDPs"."MemberNo")
    AND ("MembershipUDPs"."PropertyID" = N'TF')
   WHERE ("Memberships"."IsProspect" = N'N')
     AND ("Memberships"."JoinDate" BETWEEN '20140701 00:00:00.0' AND
                                           '20150630 23:59:59.997'
          AND ("Memberships"."PaidToDate" >= "Memberships"."JoinDate"
           OR "Memberships"."TermDate" IS NULL)
         )
```

I edited this after receiving a comment about the full code

Comment: unless you show the full query, it is difficult to answer.

Comment: That case expression can only ever return one value so if you're getting multiple rows then something else is the reason. Please show the entire query.

Comment: the full code is now shown

Comment: There must be more than one matching row in `MembershipPlans` or `MembershipUDPS` (or both in which case you'd get four records). If for example there is more than one row in `MembershipPlans`, which record do you want to use? I guess it would be the most recent?

Comment: @Chris Can members have more than one MembershipPlan or UDP? As far as I can tell that would be the only reason for you to get multiple rows.

Comment: I'm guessing this is SQL Server based on the dbo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I eventually fixed this.  The reason I used the outer joins was because the relationship between the tables was either none to many, but I rewrote the query using sub queries.  The formatting for the SQL is created via Yellowin:

```
SELECT 
   T0.C0,
   T1.C0,
   T2.C0,
   CASE
      WHEN T1.C0 IS NULL
      AND T2.C0 IS NULL THEN 1
   END,
   CASE
      WHEN T2.C0 = 'NM' THEN 'New to PHI'
      WHEN T1.C0 IS NOT NULL
      OR T2.C0 IS NOT NULL THEN 'Transferred'
      ELSE 'New to PHI'
   END,
   T0.C1
FROM (
   SELECT DISTINCT
      "Memberships"."MemberNo" AS C0,
      COUNT("Memberships"."MemberNo") AS C1
   FROM "dbo"."Memberships"
   WHERE (
      "Memberships"."IsProspect" = N'N'
   )
   AND (
      (
         "Memberships"."PaidToDate" > "Memberships"."JoinDate"
         OR "Memberships"."HealthTermEntryDate" IS NULL
      )
      AND "Memberships"."JoinDate" BETWEEN '20150701 00:00:00.0' AND '20160630 23:59:59.997'
   )
   GROUP BY 
      "Memberships"."MemberNo"

) T0
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
   SELECT DISTINCT
      "MembershipPlans"."PrevFundID" AS C0,
      "Memberships"."MemberNo" AS C1
   FROM "dbo"."Memberships"
   INNER JOIN "dbo"."MembershipPlans"
   ON (
      "Memberships"."MemberNo" = "MembershipPlans"."MemberNo"
   )
   WHERE (
      "Memberships"."IsProspect" = N'N'
   )
   AND (
      "MembershipPlans"."IsPrevCover" IN (N'Y')
   )

) T1
ON T0.C0 = T1.C1
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
   SELECT DISTINCT
      "MembershipUDPs"."Property" AS C0,
      "MembershipUDPs"."MemberNo" AS C1
   FROM "dbo"."Memberships"
   LEFT OUTER JOIN "dbo"."MembershipUDPs"
   ON (
      "Memberships"."MemberNo" = "MembershipUDPs"."MemberNo"
   )
   WHERE (
      "Memberships"."IsProspect" = N'N'
   )
   AND (
      "MembershipUDPs"."PropertyID" IN (N'TF   ')
      AND "Memberships"."JoinDate" >= '20150608 00:00:00.0'
   )

) T2
ON T0.C0 = T2.C1
```

Answer (score 1):

The LEFT OUTER JOIN chain is causing the issue here.  You want *either* rows from the MembershipPlans table *or* MembershipUDPS table, but not both.  There are some extraneous conditions in the SQL as well; you don't need two case statements and the parens could be tripping you up (in fact they could be tripping *me* up, this code is kind of hard to read).

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   "Memberships"."MemberNo",
    CASE
      WHEN PrevFundID IS NOT NULL  THEN PrevFundID
      WHEN JOINDATE >= DATEADD(mm, -3, GETDATE()) THEN Property 
      ELSE 'New to PHI' 
    END,
   "MembershipPlans"."PrevFundID",
   NULL
FROM "dbo"."Memberships"
INNER JOIN "dbo"."MembershipPlans"
ON "Memberships"."MemberNo" = "MembershipPlans"."MemberNo"
WHERE "Memberships"."IsProspect" = N'N'
AND "Memberships"."JoinDate" BETWEEN '20140701 00:00:00.0' AND '20150630 23:59:59.997'
AND ("Memberships"."PaidToDate" >= "Memberships"."JoinDate"
      OR "Memberships"."TermDate" IS NULL)
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT
   "Memberships"."MemberNo",
    CASE
      WHEN PrevFundID IS NOT NULL  THEN PrevFundID
      WHEN JOINDATE >= DATEADD(mm, -3, GETDATE()) THEN Property 
      ELSE 'New to PHI' 
    END,
   NULL,
   "MembershipUDPs"."Property",
FROM "dbo"."Memberships"
INNER JOIN "dbo"."MembershipUDPs"
ON "Memberships"."MemberNo" = "MembershipUDPs"."MemberNo"
WHERE "Memberships"."IsProspect" = N'N'
AND "Memberships"."JoinDate" BETWEEN '20140701 00:00:00.0' AND '20150630 23:59:59.997'
AND ("Memberships"."PaidToDate" >= "Memberships"."JoinDate"
      OR "Memberships"."TermDate" IS NULL)
```

If you want the same *column*, then take out the NULLs in the projection list (the `SELECT ...NULL` in the top of the query).